# Proper way to pass data from model to controller

Tags: codeigniter, object

I have a model which gets a complex data from my database (from one or more tables sometimes). They are all about some -lets say- a student. Shall I have a Student class such that I create an instance of it inside my model, and fill its properties and return it to controller.

- Can I do that, is that weird?

Answer (score 0):

It's not weird.  Sounds quite normal in an MVC world.  If the first model is something like StudentRegister, then it is in charge of finding Students given some criteria.  It would be appropriate for the data retrieved to be modelled itself as a collection of Students and returned to the client of StudentRegister as such.  So, for example, you could have

```
class StudenteRegister extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->ci = & get_instance();

   $this->ci->load->model('student');
}

public function findStudent($studentid)
{
   $student = null; // will hold Student object once constructed
   // some code to query database and construct Student object
   return $student;
}
```

Comment: what if I need a new Student(); I mean, once I load it, it's constructor is called once. I mean what to do if separated two Student objects is needed.